# Within pointless topology inside of choiceless constructivism, prove that division is possible

Tags: topos-theory, constructive-mathematics, locales

In [Frank Waaldijk's paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10699-004-3065-z) on the foundations of constructive analysis, Waaldijk shows that various definitions of "continuous function" for functions of the form $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ in constructive analysis have undesirable properties when Brouwer's Fan Theorem is denied, such as:

- They might not be closed under composition.
- The function $x \mapsto 1/x : \mathbb R_{\neq 0} \to \mathbb R_{\neq 0}$ may not be continuous under some of these definitions.
- It may not be possible to define a functional $\int_0^1$ over these functions with the desired properties.

My intuition is that Brouwer's Fan Theorem asserts the compactness of $[0,1]$ in a way that is compatible with theories of computable analysis like Type Two Effectivity. Once it's assumed, it's then possible to prove propositions like the existence of a functional $\int_0^1$ on continuous functions of the form $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$. But of course, the Fan Theorem is a proposition which might fail in some versions of constructive logic, which could be argued is a problem.

It is folklore that pointless topology can get around these problems. On top of that, it's argued that not only is Brouwer's Fan Theorem not needed, but nor is Dependent Choice nor Countable Choice. As such, I'm wondering whether the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ can be defined and shown to be continuous in a way that is valid in all toposes. The domain and codomain of this function should be $\mathbb R_{\neq 0}$ (as a locale and *not* a set).

The inspiration comes from my second bullet point. I apologise if I've misunderstood something.

Comment: There is an explicit presentation of the locale $\mathbb{R}$ by generator and relations, generated by rational interval $]a,b[$ with the relations that corresponds to the definition of dedekind cut.  Working on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ for simplicity you can just define $I^*(]a,b[) = ]b^{-1}, a^{-1} [$ for all rational numbers $a,b >0$ and check that it is compatible to the relation generating the locales to get a function $I:\mathbb{R}_+^* \to \mathbb{R}_+^*$.

Comment: @SimonHenry Thanks! That helps a lot

Comment: Note: the only relations to consider between rational interval to consider are are the obvious inclusions and $]a,b[ = \bigcup_{a<c<d<b} ]c,d[$.

Comment: Just a minor remark: when you write $R_{\neq 0}$, you should take care to mean by that the locale corresponding to $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < 0 \lor x > 0\}$, rather than $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \lnot (x = 0)\}$. Of course, the locale in question is just the sum of two copies of $\mathbb{R}_+$ that Simon mentions in his comment.